# Who is the Rishi Lamagayana, relative of Agni’s wife Svaha?

Tags: vedas, rishi, agni, atharva-veda

[This excerpt](http://gdurl.com/lPEl) from the Gopatha Brahmana of the Atharvana Veda describes the goddess Svaha, wife of Agni the fire god:

> Svaha was born of truth, she was made by the Brahman, and **she is of the same lineage of (the seer) Lamagayana**; she has two syllables, one word, three colours: white, red and gold. She is like a compound of all the metres in the Vedas, she has one snort at the end of the syllables, the four Vedas (and) the six auxiliaries to the Vedas are her two bodies; herbs and trees are hair on the body.  Sun and moon are her eyes.  She is Svaha, she is Svadha. She is used like a Vashat call at the sacrifices. Agni is her divinity, her form is a Brahmana.

A lot of this passage is about the word Svaha and its use in Vedic Yagnas.  But I’m interested in the part in bold.  My question is, who is the Rishi Lamagayana who belongs to the same Gotra or lineage as Svaha?

And what is that Gotra?  The Mahabharata [describes](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03223.htm) Svaha as the daughter of Daksha, so is Lamagayana related to Daksha?

Comment: Is it possible that the seer is Samagayana and not Lamagayana?

Comment: @Surya The only variant given in the footnotes is that sometimes it’s spelled Lamakayana rather than Lamagayana.